# How to un-nest dataframe items separated by `;`?

Tags: r, nested, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have an un-tidy data frame saved as a tidyverse Tibble called `data` like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  `Full name` `Favorite foods`                            `Preferred colors`
  <chr>       <chr>                                       <chr>             
1 Homer       key lime pie; celery; fried rice            green; red        
2 Marge       celery; ice cream                           NA                
3 Mr. Burns   fried rice; apple; fried chicken; ice cream orange; purple    
4 Krusty      celery; key lime pie; apple                 red; blue
```

It can be recreated like this:

```
data <- tribble(
    ~"Full name", ~"Favorite foods", ~"Preferred colors", 
    "Homer", "key lime pie; celery; fried rice", "green; red", 
    "Marge", "celery; ice cream", NA, 
    "Mr. Burns", "fried rice; apple; fried chicken; ice cream", "orange; purple", 
    "Krusty", "celery; key lime pie; apple", "red; blue"
)
```

As you can see, it lists people's `Favorite foods` and `Preferred colors`, where each element is a `chr` within which items are separated by `;`, such as `celery; ice cream`.

Ultimately, I would like to separately analyze and visualize people's favorite foods and colors. Such as by being able to say, "The top two most favorite foods are x and y"; or "No one prefers black".

How do I tidy this data so that it reshapes/processes the foods and colors into a tidy data frame? For example, could the food and color columns be converted into their own nested data frames? Or is there a better/simpler way to go?

A tidyverse solution is not required but *strongly preferred* because that's what I am most familiar with. Computational performance is nice but not a strong consideration in this case.

**EDIT:** For future-proofing, I might also have columns in this data that I do *not* want to split.

Comment: You can use `tidyr::separate_rows(data, \`Favorite foods\`)` into separate frames, one for foods, one for colors. This allows a little more _not-nested-frame_ access to the data for simpler interactive work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_split` to create list-columns:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(-`Full name`, ~ str_split(.x, pattern = "; ")))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  `Full name` `Favorite foods` `Preferred colors`
  <chr>       <list>           <list>            
1 Homer       <chr [3]>        <chr [2]>         
2 Marge       <chr [2]>        <chr [1]>         
3 Mr. Burns   <chr [4]>        <chr [2]>         
4 Krusty      <chr [3]>        <chr [2]>
```

To make it fully tidy, I'd recommend pivoting:

```r
data %>%
  mutate(across(-1, ~ str_split(.x, pattern = "; "))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  unnest_longer("value")

# A tibble: 19 × 3
   `Full name` name             value        
   <chr>       <chr>            <chr>        
 1 Homer       Favorite foods   key lime pie 
 2 Homer       Favorite foods   celery       
 3 Homer       Favorite foods   fried rice   
 4 Homer       Preferred colors green        
 5 Homer       Preferred colors red          
 6 Marge       Favorite foods   celery       
 7 Marge       Favorite foods   ice cream    
 8 Marge       Preferred colors NA           
 9 Mr. Burns   Favorite foods   fried rice   
10 Mr. Burns   Favorite foods   apple        
11 Mr. Burns   Favorite foods   fried chicken
12 Mr. Burns   Favorite foods   ice cream    
13 Mr. Burns   Preferred colors orange       
14 Mr. Burns   Preferred colors purple       
15 Krusty      Favorite foods   celery       
16 Krusty      Favorite foods   key lime pie 
17 Krusty      Favorite foods   apple        
18 Krusty      Preferred colors red          
19 Krusty      Preferred colors blue
```

Comment: Not a fan of using magic numbers to address columns, rather than column names: in general future-proof code cannot make assumptions about the order of rows, *nor* columns.

Comment: Ahah good point, it was a bit faster to do but I agree

Comment: Good points, is there a way to make use of `separate_longer_delim` or `separate_rows` avoid the magic numbers? I like the final outcome in this answer, but would prefer future-proofing it as much as possible.

Comment: You can avoid the magic numbers simply by naming the column you want to include or exclude. I'll edit the first option. `1` is the position of the column

Comment: Thanks @Maël one more thing: There might also be columns in the data frame that I do NOT want to split, will your answer support that?

Comment: Then, use inclusion rather than include in across: `c(\`Favorite foods\`,  \`Preferred colors\`)`

Comment: Oh @Maël in case you're still here, what does the tilde symbol `~` do in the `mutate` line????

Answer (score 2):

As per r2evans’ comment, but using the new function [`separate_longer_delim`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_longer_delim.html) from ‘tidyr’ that supersedes [`separate_rows`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html):

```
data |>
    separate_longer_delim(`Favorite foods`, delim = '; ') |>
    separate_longer_delim(`Preferred colors`, delim = '; ')
# A tibble: 22 × 3
#    `Full name` `Favorite foods` `Preferred colors`
#    <chr>       <chr>            <chr>
#  1 Homer       key lime pie     green
#  2 Homer       key lime pie     red
#  3 Homer       celery           green
#  4 Homer       celery           red
#  5 Homer       fried rice       green
#  …
```

But note that this assumes that there is a relationship between the foods and colours, which is probably not the case; Maël’s answer provides a better structure in the more likely case that these are unrelated preferences.

Comment: Although a valid option, this is IMO not very tidy because it repeats information in the column that has more information than the other.

Comment: @Maël Ah that's a good point, I completely misunderstood the data when skimming it. Your answer is almost certainly better.